# I get Error 401 when I send a POST request to an excluded endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot-security

I'm developing a web app where user can authenticate with OAuth2. In the web app there are a list of endpoints that are accessible only by sending requests (GET-POST-PUT-DELETE) including a valid token.
Now I want to implement my web app by allowing users to authenticate with username and password. There is a form where user can Signup to the web app (they need to fill the form with the required data).
So, once an user clicked on Signup, a POST request is sent to the URL **localhost:8080/api/v1/accounts/register** and their data are stored into the db.
My problem is that the POST request works only if a valid token is included into the request. If I don't specify a valid token, I get an "error 401 unauthorized". If I send the request by including the token, I got 201.
What I tried to do was to make the endpoint (/api/v1/accounts/register) accessible to everyone. But I still get the error 401.

Those are the classes involved into the authorization:

SecurityConfig.java:

```
package it.app.demoaimeetingroombe.configuration;

import it.app.demoaimeetingroombe.csrf.CsrfTokenCustom;
import it.app.demoaimeetingroombe.filter.AccountCheckFilterChain;
import it.app.demoaimeetingroombe.repository.AccountRepository;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, AccountRepository accountRepository) throws Exception {
        List<AntPathRequestMatcher> excludeFromCheck = List.of(
                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/v1/accounts/authenticate"),
                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/v1/rooms/*/bookings/daily/*"),
                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger-ui/**"),
                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger-ui.html"),
                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/v1/accounts/register"),
                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/v3/api-docs/**"),
                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/v1/webauthn/**")
        );

        return http
                .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(customCsrfTokenRepository())
                .ignoringRequestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/v1/webauthn/**"))
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                        .requestMatchers(
                                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/v1/rooms/*/bookings/daily/*"),
                                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger-ui/**"),
                                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger-ui.html"),
                                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/v1/accounts/register"),
                                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/v3/api-docs/**"),
                                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/v1/webauthn/**")).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .addFilterAfter(new AccountCheckFilterChain(accountRepository, excludeFromCheck), BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .and()
                .and().cors().configurationSource(httpServletRequest -> {
                    CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
                    corsConfiguration.setAllowedOriginPatterns(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:3000"));
                    corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                    corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
                    corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                    corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("Authorization"));
                    corsConfiguration.setMaxAge(3600L);
                    return corsConfiguration;
                })
                .and().build();
    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository customCsrfTokenRepository() {
        return new CsrfTokenCustom();
    }
}
```

AccountCheckFilterChain.java:

```
package it.app.demoaimeetingroombe.filter;


import it.app.demoaimeetingroombe.repository.AccountRepository;
import jakarta.servlet.*;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class AccountCheckFilterChain implements Filter {
    private final AccountRepository accountRepository;
    private final List<AntPathRequestMatcher> excludeFromCheck;

    public AccountCheckFilterChain(AccountRepository accountRepository, List<AntPathRequestMatcher> excludeFromCheck) {
        this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
        this.excludeFromCheck = excludeFromCheck;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = ((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest);
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse);
        boolean shouldExclude = excludeFromCheck.stream().anyMatch(exclude -> exclude.matches(httpRequest));
        if (!shouldExclude) {
            Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            if (authentication == null) {
                setUnauthorized(httpResponse);
                return;
            }
            String accountId = authentication.getName();
            if (StringUtils.isBlank(accountId) || !accountRepository.existsByIdAndIsActiveTrue(accountId)) {
                setUnauthorized(httpResponse);
                return;
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    private static void setUnauthorized(HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
        httpResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        httpResponse.setContentType("application/json");
        httpResponse.setContentLength(0);
    }
}
```

CsrfTokenCustom.java:

```
package it.app.demoaimeetingroombe.csrf;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfToken;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.DefaultCsrfToken;

public class CsrfTokenCustom implements CsrfTokenRepository {
    private final CookieCsrfTokenRepository delegate = CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();

    @Override
    public CsrfToken generateToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return delegate.generateToken(request);
    }

    @Override
    public void saveToken(CsrfToken token, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        delegate.saveToken(token, request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public CsrfToken loadToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        CsrfToken token = delegate.loadToken(request);
        if (isWebAuthnEndpoint(request)) {
            String newToken = "ALLOW_ALL";
            return new DefaultCsrfToken(token.getHeaderName(), token.getParameterName(), newToken);
        }
        return token;
    }

    private boolean isWebAuthnEndpoint(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
        return requestURI.startsWith("/api/v1/webauthn/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used Spring Security to manage authentication and permission in your web project based on the code you gave. You need help because you want to make the `/api/v1/accounts/register` endpoint publicly available, but it requires a valid token to access.

You must alter your `SecurityConfig` class to make the `/api/v1/accounts/register` endpoint available without authentication. This endpoint is now included in the `excludeFromCheck` list, which implies that authentication checks should not be performed on it. It is still viewed as an authenticated request though.

To resolve this, try out updating the `SecurityConfig` class in this way,

```
//... 
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, AccountRepository accountRepository) throws Exception {
    List<AntPathRequestMatcher> excludeFromCheck = List.of(
        //...

        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/v1/accounts/register")
    );

    return http
        //...
        .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
            .requestMatchers(excludeFromCheck.toArray(new AntPathRequestMatcher[0])).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I modified the code as you suggested, I sent the POST request without include the token and I still get the error 401.